# Dijkstra's algorithm - JavaScript implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the JavaScript library at
https://github.com/andrewhayward/dijkstra

I don't understand this line:

```
var map = {a:{b:3,c:1},b:{a:2,c:1},c:{a:4,b:1}}
```

There are three nodes: `a,b,c`. I interpret `a:{b:3,c:1}`, as follows. The cost form `a` to `b` is 3. Then `b:{a:2,c:1}` is the cost from `b` to `a`, which is 2.

That doesn't make sense. a to b is 3, but `b` to `a` is 2.

How do you guys read it?

Comment: you're reading it right

Comment: @JaromandaX, but how can the same path have multiple weights? if a to b costs 3, then surely, b to a also costs 3.

Comment: but it's not the same path - it's the reverse path

Comment: It's not the same path, is it? Suppose it describes an escalator going down. Then going up costs more effort.

Comment: oh, thanks guys. I guess all the examples I've seen, have the same weights for the forward and reverse path. So just to confirm, this image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dijkstra_Animation.gif has the same weight in both directions?

Comment: its normal on networking world, you can have two different line for same locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Dijkstra's algorithm implementation work for directed graph, this means path form A to B is not the same as B to A, that's why you can have different weights on A->B and B->A.